# Rotate ThreeJS Object3D on a tilted Y axis

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've tried many ways to tilt my object then rotate it on this tilted axis, but no matter what I try it always rotates as though the Y axis is straight up, it doesn't seem to rotate on this new tilted axis, WHY NOT?

```
this.axis = new Vector3(0, 0, 0.5).normalize()
this.mesh = new Mesh(this.geometry, this.material)
this.mesh.rotateOnAxis(this.axis, Math.degToRad(25))
```

I've tried using `rotateOnWorldAxis`, also tried `makeRotationAxis` on `Matrix4` and applying directly to geometry.

Example here:

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/threejs-bare-example-uuf23)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this; one solution would be to add additional hierarchy to your scene by introducing a [`group`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Group) node. Here the `group` is added as a child to the `scene`, and your `mesh` is added as a child to that `group`:

```
this.mesh = new Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);

/* New group */
this.group = new THREE.Group();
/* Tilt group */
this.group.rotateOnAxis(this.axis, Math.degToRad(25));
/* Add mesh to group */
this.group.add( this.mesh );
/* Add group to scene */
this.scene.add( group );
```

With this added hierarchy, the "axis tilt" is applied to the [`group`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Group) instead of to the `mesh`. In threejs, doing this causes any children (ie `mesh`) of the `group` to inherit that tilt as well.

This method provides an intuitive way of combing the tilt with locally applied rotation (ie as you are doing via `rotation.y += 0.005`) to achieve the desired axis based rotation.

Here's a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/threejs-bare-example-try6s). Hope that helps!

#### Alternative method

Alternatively, you could use the `rotateY()` method to apply a rotation transform around the `mesh` object's local frame:

```
this.mesh.rotateY(0.005);

// this.mesh.rotation.y += 0.005 <-- not needed
```

Here's a [working example to demonstrate](https://codesandbox.io/s/threejs-bare-example-pg81v) this approach

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, I'm aware of this solution but I'm interested in how to do this without adding extra objects to the hierarchy

Comment: Sure, I've just included another method - does that help?

Comment: OMG so it was there all along, would you mind explaining what the difference is between the rotateY method and using the y property of the rotation object? I've accepted your answer :)

Comment: Thanks :) my understanding is that the `rotateY()` method applies the rotation transform prior to the world transform of the object which means the y rotation is applied before the tilt is applied, where as the `rotation.y += ..` applies the rotation "after the fact", causing rotation about the y "after the tilt" is applied